# Console.Read() does not capture the right information

Tags: c#

I'm running a very simple program that just prompts the user for a number, and for now, just prints it on the screen. But for some reason that I do not know of, the number i enter seems to add to the number 48.

for example:
I enter 2
and it puts out 50

Is there some sort of fundamental law that I'am overseeing, or some sort of mistake I've made in my code

I'm a beginner, if you hadn't noticed

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int Num;
            Console.WriteLine("Please Input Number of Rows you want to make in your pyrimid: ");
            Num = Console.Read();

            Console.WriteLine(Num);// Just to check if it is getting the right number
            Console.Read();//This is Here just so the console window doesn't close when the program runs

        }
    }
}
```

edit: Hate to be a bother but now getting this error for `num = int.Parse(Console.Read());` as The best overloaded method match for 'int.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments. Does this mean that i need an overload method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Console.Read` returns `char` so when you cast it to `int` yo get the ASCII code of `2` which is **50**! You should parse to int instead of (implicitly) casting it:

```
Num = int.Parse(Console.Read());
```

Notes:

1. If the  input can be a non numeric value, use `int.TryParse`
2. The convention to  local variables in C# is camelCase, so change `Num` to `num`.

Comment: Int32.Parse seems much better!

Comment: @AppDeveloper, in what way it is better?! do you declare variables with `Int32`? cuz it is the same thing you know.

Comment: Do i need to import a library? I'm getting 'int' does not contain a definition for 'parse'?

Comment: well i said that for naming convention using the Class name defined in BCL when a static method is used, rather than the alias name!

Comment: @user2224223 - the `p` of the parse must be upper case!

Comment: @user2224223, no, it was my fault, it is **Parse** not **parse**.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.Read` returns the character code and not the character itself.

```
char num = (char)Console.Read();
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(num.ToString()));
```

This code is not ideal but it shows what is happening. Since you are expecting a digit to be entered you can also use

```
int num = Console.Read() - 48;
```

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read` reads reads byte from Standard Input.

`2` has a ASCII value of `50`

You need to parse the value read from the console

```
Num = Int32.Parse(Console.Read()); // or Num = int.Parse(Console.Read());
```